# Hiding parent HTML content when all of it's child elements are not visible

Tags: jquery

I have a programme with the following HTML structure:

```
<div class="day-container">
    <h2>Day X</h2>
    <div class="session-container">
        <div class="panel">SESSION TITLE</div>
        <div class="presentation-container">
            <div class="panel">PRESENTATION</div>
        </div>
        <div class="presentation-container">
            <div class="panel">PRESENTATION</div>
        </div>
        <div class="presentation-container">
            <div class="panel">PRESENTATION</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="session-container">
        <div class="panel">SESSION TITLE</div>
        <div class="presentation-container">
            <div class="panel">PRESENTATION</div>
        </div>
        <div class="presentation-container">
            <div class="panel">PRESENTATION</div>
        </div>
        <div class="presentation-container">
            <div class="panel">PRESENTATION</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And I'm attempting to show/hide content from a free text search box using jQuery. I can successfully show/hide the specific `.presentation-container` on these results, but I'd also like to hide `.session-container` and even `.day-container` when no search results show up in them, but I'm not sure how to do this.

Do I need to use `.is(':visible')` at all?

```
$('input#search').on('search input', function() {
    var query = $(this).val().toLowerCase();

    if (query) {
        $('div.presentation-container').each(function() {
            var textContent = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
            if (textContent.indexOf(query) === -1) {
                $(this).hide();
            } else {
                $(this).show();
            }
        });
    } else {
        $('div.panel').show();
    }
});
```

[Example jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f6gm9y3v/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've edited the code so that it iterates through each day, each day's sessions, and each session's presentations. It then checks if all of these are hidden and hides the parent accordingly (e.g. if all presentations are hidden, it hides the session, then checks if all sessions are hidden and hides the day, etc.)

```js
$('input#search').on('search input', function() {
    var query = $(this).val().toLowerCase();

    if (query) {
        var dayContainers = $('div.day-container');

        // Iterate through each day, each day's sessions, and each session's presentations.
        dayContainers.each(function() {
           var sessionContainers = $(this).find('div.session-container');

           sessionContainers.each(function() {
               var presentationContainers = $(this).find('div.presentation-container');

               presentationContainers.each(function() {
                   var textContent = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
                   if (textContent.indexOf(query) === -1) {
                       $(this).hide();
                   } else {
                       $(this).show();
                   }
               });

               // Filter any presentations that have been hidden.
               var hiddenPresentations = presentationContainers.filter(':hidden');

               // If all of this session's presentations are hidden, hide the session.
               if (presentationContainers.length === hiddenPresentations.length) {
                   $(this).hide();
               } else {
                   $(this).show();
               }
           });

           // Perform the same check on the session containers.
           var hiddenSessions = sessionContainers.filter(':hidden');

           if (sessionContainers.length === hiddenSessions.length) {
               $(this).hide();
           } else {
               $(this).show();
           }
        });
    } else {
        // Show any previously-hidden days/sessions/presentations.
        $('div.panel, div.day-container, div.session-container, div.presentation-container').show();
    }
});
```

```css
h2 {
  margin: 0;
}

.session-container {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  background: lightgray;
}

.panel {
  font-weight: 700;
}

.presentation-container {
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: solid 1px gray;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  <input id="search" name="search" type="search" placeholder="Search...">
</p>
<div class="day-container">
  <h2>
    DAY 1
  </h2>
  <div class="session-container">
    <div class="panel">
      Session Title
    </div>
    <div class="presentation-container">
      Presentation One
    </div>
    <div class="presentation-container">
      Presentation Two
    </div>
    <div class="presentation-container">
      Presentation Three
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="session-container">
    <div class="panel">
      Session Title
    </div>
    <div class="presentation-container">
      Presentation Four
    </div>
    <div class="presentation-container">
      Presentation Five
    </div>
    <div class="presentation-container">
      Presentation Six
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="day-container">
  <h2>
    DAY 2
  </h2>
  <div class="session-container">
    <div class="panel">
      Session Title
    </div>
    <div class="presentation-container">
      Presentation Seven
    </div>
    <div class="presentation-container">
      Presentation Eight
    </div>
    <div class="presentation-container">
      Presentation Nine
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="session-container">
    <div class="panel">
      Session Title
    </div>
    <div class="presentation-container">
      Presentation Ten
    </div>
    <div class="presentation-container">
      Presentation Eleven
    </div>
    <div class="presentation-container">
      Presentation Twelve
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```